# C# - Can't insert data into MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, winforms

I am making an application where I scrape a certain website. The website has a bunch of players, and I scrape each one of their profile pages. Their profile pages contains information like Name, Level, World and Last Login date.

So I made an object called Player. And then I add all their data to a list.

```
public static List<Player> Players = new List<Player> { };

public class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Vocation { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public int Achievements { get; set; }
        public string World { get; set; }
        public string LastLogin { get; set; }
        public string AccountStatus { get; set; }
        public int OnlineStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

I add the data like this:

```
new Player { Name = playerName, Sex = playerSex, Vocation = playerVocation, Level = playerLevel, Achievements = playerAchievements, World = playerWorld, LastLogin = playerLastLogin, AccountStatus = playerAccountStatus, OnlineStatus = playerOnlineStatus };
```

I now want to add all the players to my MySQL database, but I cannot seem to understand how to insert the data.

I established a connection and I tried to SELECT data and it works fine. So my connection is not bad. But inserting seems to not work.

Here's my code I add to insert the data into the tables:

```
string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=rookstat;Uid=XXXXXXX;password=XXXXXX;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

foreach (Player rooker in Players)
{
command.CommandText = "Insert into rookstayers (id, name, sex, vocation, level, achievements, world, lastlogin, accountstatus, onlinestatus) values('', rooker.Name, rooker.Sex, rooker.Vocation, rooker.Level, rooker.Achievements, rooker.World, rooker.LastLogin, rooker.AccountStatus, rooker.OnlineStatus)";
conn.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

conn.Close();
```

What am I doing wrong? I am unsure about the values i insert. Is it supposed to be rooker.Name or what?

Comment: You have string data where variables should be. You should look up how to use parameters with your query, it will solve your problem. As it is, you have a string with the names of the variables in it, which does nothing because it doesn't dereference internally in the string (at least not in C#5, C#6 does, but the syntax is different).

Comment: I tried inserting data manually and I did it like this: values('1', 'hello') and that worked. shouldnt i be able to just enter the strings instead of the '

Comment: No, I don't think you get what i'm saying... `"INSERT (..) VALUES (myvariable)"` isn't the same as `"INSERT (..) VALUES (" + myvariable + ")"`

Comment: Aha! I will try that and see if it works

Comment: See the answers you have below, they are 100x better solutions since they won't require you to escape or convert your values into the correct format strings for the database, plus its good practice to keep you from getting SQL injection attacks or simply failing on bad data (if the input has a ' in it, your query will fail).

Comment: @aliazik I would also like to add to use MySQLCommand.Prepare() since you are using the same SQL command multiple times. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{
    connection.Open();
    using(var command = new MySqlCommand()) 
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO rookstayers (name, sex, vocation, level, achievements, world, lastlogin, accountstatus, onlinestatus) VALUES (@name, @sex, @vocation, @level, @achievements, @world, @lastLogin, @accountStatus, @onlineStatus)";
        command.Prepare();

        foreach(var rooker in Players) 
        {
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", rooker.Name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", rooker.Sex);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vocation", rooker.Vocation);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", rooker.Level);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@achievements", rooker.Achievements);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@world", rooker.World);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastLogin", rooker.LastLogin);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountStatus", rooker.AccountStatus);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@onlineStatus", rooker.OnlineStatus);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the differences:

1. Wrapping disposable objects (i.e. MySQLConnection and MySQLCommand)
   in using statements.
2. Updated the SQL insert command to use SQL Parameters. In this case, "@name" will be replaced with the value of rooker.Name when the command is executed.
3. Excluded id column in the insert statement as I assume that is the
   identity column so you don't have to explicitly include that.
4. Lastly, use of command.Prepare(). As specified in the MySQL .NET
       Connector documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html), it can can provide significant
       performance improvements on queries that are executed more than once.

Answer (score 6):

The way in which you build your query creates a single string with your variables names treated as literal strings.

Instead you need a parameterized query like this

```
string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=rookstat;Uid=XXXXXXX;password=XXXXXX;";
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
using(MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    command.CommandText = @"Insert into rookstayers 
             (id, name, sex,   vocation, level, achievements, 
              world, lastlogin, accountstatus, onlinestatus) 
       values('', @name, @sex, @vocation, @level, @Achievements,
              @World, @LastLogin, @AccountStatus, @OnlineStatus)";

    command.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@sex", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@vocation", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@level", MySqlDbType.Int32);
    .... and so on for all the parameters placeholders

    command.Prepare();
    foreach (Player rooker in Players)
    {
          command.Parameters["@name"].Value = rooker.Name;
          command.Parameters["@sex"].Value = rooker.Sex;
          command.Parameters["@vocation"].Value = rooker.Vocation;
          command.Parameters["@level"].Value = rooker.Level;

          ... and so on for the other parameters defined
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

In this way, BEFORE entering the loop, you define your sql command and create the parameters in the MySqlCommand Parameters collection without setting the values. And, as suggested below by Mr adding the call to command.Prepare could enhance the performance.

Inside the loop, for each parameter defined, you could set its value and call the command to execute.

I wish also to point to the using statement that ensure the proper closing and disposing of the objects and the use of Add with proper parameter type set for each parameter instead of AddWithValue. AddWithValue is a shortcut with numerous drawbacks as you can read in this article [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

A last advice, if this kind of transformations between objects and data happens very often then you should invest a bit of your time to learn to use an ORM tool like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

EDIT: Looking at your whole code, it seems that you miss an important step in your scraping. You need to add the Player to your list of Players

```
private async void insertTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (onlineList.Items.Count > 0)
     {
         for (int i=0; i<onlineList.Items.Count; i++)
         {
              CurrentPlayer = onlineList.Items[i].ToString();
              var playerProfile = await GetData();
              foreach (var row in playerProfile)
              {
                  .... gets player data ....
              }

              // Creates a new Player and add to the insertion list
              Players.Add(new Player 
              { 
                    Name = playerName, 
                    Sex = playerSex, 
                    Vocation = playerVocation, 
                    Level = playerLevel, 
                    Achievements = playerAchievements, 
                    World = playerWorld, 
                    LastLogin = playerLastLogin, 
                    AccountStatus = playerAccountStatus, 
                    OnlineStatus = playerOnlineStatus 
               };
          }

          // And now the inserts goes here
          .......
```

Comment: will try it, hang on!

Comment: I just can't get it to work. I literally have no idea what I am doing wrong. I tried to print out the values in Player (name/vocation/level etc...) and it prints correct values. But whenever I try insert them to database it's like they are null, nothing happens

Comment: Did you see them with the debugger? Did you check if the loop is executed? Could you change the insert to this one `int rowsAdded = command.ExecuteNonQuery();` and then print the value of rowsAdded?

Comment: It executes the loop but it's all just blank. It's as if the .Name, .Level, .Vocation etc.. is just blanked out

Comment: So when you look at the value of rooker.Name it is blank when inside the loop? This doesn't seem to be happening here. None assigns a new value inside the foreach loop to the rooken properties.

Comment: Nowhere in your code you add the Player extracted to your list of players. Perhaps I am tired by I can't see anywhere a `Players.Add(Player)`

Comment: `new Player { Name = playerName, Sex = playerSex, ....}` isn't that creating a new player in the list? Or should it be wrapped in a `Players.Add(new Player { Name =.....`

Comment: @aliazik Yes, it should be added to  the Players list.

Comment: @aliazik Yes it creates a new Player but the reference to it is immediately lost because you don't add it to the list that you later use to insert the data....

Comment: This is not caused by the Add but by the fact that one or more of your players object has no Name (failing to retrieve it from the site?) and the database doesn't like it. Please use the debugger, you will resolve these errors a lot faster

Answer (score 4):

You are passing string literals to the query, not the variable values:

Try adjusting your query to:

```
command.CommandText = "Insert into rookstayers (id, name, sex, vocation) values('', @name, @sex, @vocation)";
```

Then `Parameters.AddWithValue` as shown below:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", rooker.Name);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", rooker.Sex);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vocation", rooker.Vocation);
```

etc

This will also help prevent SQL injection.

Comment: You should show how to place the `@name` in the query too.

Comment: Where exactly should I add that? Like this? `foreach (Player rooker in Players)
                {
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", rooker.Name);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", rooker.Sex);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vocation", rooker.Vocation);
                    command.CommandText = "Insert into rookstayers (id, name, sex, vocation, level, achievements, world, lastlogin, accountstatus, onlinestatus) values('', @name, @sex, @vocation.....)
                    conn.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }`

Comment: Ahhhh god damnit, it didn't insert anything :(

Comment: @aliazik - do you receive an error? Is the object `rooker` populated with values?

Comment: It still is not working. No errors. Check my code here: http://pastebin.com/yx7qhmz2

Comment: @aliazik - just took a quick look.  You have a list `Players` which never seems to be populated from what I can see.  Try adding that player to the list before your database code:

`Players.Add(new Player { Name = playerName, Sex = playerSex, Vocation = playerVocation, Level = playerLevel, Achievements = playerAchievements, World = playerWorld, LastLogin = playerLastLogin, AccountStatus = playerAccountStatus, OnlineStatus = playerOnlineStatus });`